# вместо точки иероглифы

Tags: php, html, css

есть файл с текстом хэдера для зарегестрированого пользователя, на двух страницах включаеться однаково

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <?
         if ($_SESSION["is_logged"] == true) {
                 require("includes/islogged.html");
         }
        ?>
</div>
```

сам файл:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
        <p style="color: #dadada; font-size: 16pt; margin: 0 auto auto;"><?
            echo $accessed['name'].' '.$accessed['surname']." | ";
        ?><span style="    border: 1.2pt solid;font-size: 11.5pt;background: #120e0e;border-radius: 2pt;">&nbsp;<span style="color: #ffd700;"><? echo "● ";?></span><? echo $accessed['shumik'];?> </span> &#160;&#160;</p>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group" >
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="exit" style="font-family: Comic Sans MS "><b>Exit</b></button>
        </div>
</form>
```

проблема: на одной странице "●" отображаеться нормально, на другой - "в—Џ"
в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего проблема в кодировке. Пересохраните файлы в `UTF-8` и добавьте строчку в файл `.htaccess` `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`

Comment: куда добавить? в какой тег?

Comment: @shumik_UA, в файл `.htaccess` который должен быть в корне сайта

Comment: @shumik_UA, не в тэг, а создайте отдельный файл `.htaccess`

Comment: еще посмотрел.. проблема только на денвере, закинул на сервер - все нормально.. баг только на денвере и только на 1 странице